# Super Polymerization how does it work

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My question involves the card Super Polymerization. I understand that it can be used to fusion summon using monsters on either side of the field, but it seems unclear on if those monsters have to be the ones listed on the fusion monster.

Super polymerization stats

> Discard 1 card, Fusion Summon 1 Fusion Monster from your Extra Deck, using monsters from either side of the field as Fusion Materials. Cards and effects cannot be activated in response to this card's activation.

Does that translate to the opponent has 3 random monsters that I take to summon Blue Eyes Ultimate without any Blue Eyes? Or does my opponent need to actually have a Blue Eyes for me to use?

Answer (score 4):

> Does that translate to the opponent has 3 random monsters that I take to summon Blue Eyes Ultimate without any Blue Eyes?

No, you must use the correct fusion materials for the monster you wish to fusion summon.

If superpoly let you do that it would be too broken.

The advantage of it is that is quick-play, so you can fusion summon during your opponent's turn.

This card was mostly used in Hero decks, where many of the fusion monsters have as requirements *"1 hero + some attribute-specific monster"*... So you could use your hero and (say) your opponent's dark effect monster to summon [Destiny HERO Dangerous](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Destiny_HERO_-_Dangerous).

Comment: Ok I was assuming thats what it meant but a coworker I play with was disagreeing with me about it

Comment: I see, but yes you can't do that with superpoly. The fusion materials have to be respected. The fact that it allow you to use opponent monsters is independent to that fact. Glad I could help